# HTTPS automatically reroutes to production server instead of development server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, https

Web Host: Bluehost
SSL: Wildcard SSL
Rails: v4
Ruby: v2
Dev Domain: dev.mydomain.com
Pro Domain: www.mydomain.com

I'm attempting to test out `https://` connections. I've only modified my rails app and my apache .htaccess files within the development app. I've run into a couple of problems, both of which I believe occur because of the first:

1) Biggest problem: When using http://dev.mydomain.com/whatever, everything works as expected. However when using https://dev.mydomain.com/whatever, it runs in production mode! Even though the domain is dev.mydomain.com, the rails app is running under production mode. Precompiled assets are being served...but the thing is, those files don't physically exist in the development app directory. They only exist in the production app directory (completely separate). This means that even though the URLs are pointing to dev.mydomain.com/whatever, everything is ACTUALLY running through mydomain.com/whatever...and the production application of my rails app is running. Why the hell is that?!

2) Within my .htaccess file, I've attempted to force an SSL connection using:

```
SSLOptions +StrictRequire
SSLRequireSSL
SSLRequire %{HTTP_HOST} eq "dev.mydomain.com"
ErrorDocument 403 https://dev.mydomain.com
```

However it no longer prompts me for a login/pass combo even though I've correctly set up Apache Authorization parameters. I believe this is because when SSL is used, the actual directories being used aren't the development folders at all (see 1st problem).

Is this an Apache configuration error? I haven't done anything to httpd.conf, my web host automatically set up the SSL certificate.

EDIT: "Full" .htaccess code...

```
#SSLOptions +StrictRequire
#SSLRequireSSL
#SSLRequire %{HTTP_HOST} eq "dev.mydomain.com"
#ErrorDocument 403 https://dev.mydomain.com

#AuthUserFile "/home/account/.htpasswds/htuser"
#AuthGroupFile "/home/account/.htpasswds/htgroup"
#AuthName "Login Required"
#AuthType Basic
#require group owners administrators


# General Apache options
Options -Indexes
Options -MultiViews
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI
SetEnv TZ Canada/Eastern
Header unset ETag
FileETag None
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
DefaultLanguage en


# Compress output
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/css text/js text/javascript application/javascript application/xml text/xml image/gif image/jpeg image/jpg image/png image/vnd.microsoft.icon image/x-icon application/vnd.ms-fontobject font/ttf font/otf image/svg+xml




# User added MIME types
AddType video/x-flv .flv
AddType video/mp4 .m4v .mp4 .f4v
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType audio/ogg .oga
AddType image/jpeg .jpeg .jpg .jpe
AddType image/svg+xml .svg .svgz
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType font/ttf .ttf


# Set Expires info
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 365 days"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 365 days"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 365 days"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 365 days"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 365 days"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 365 days"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 365 days"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 365 days"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 day"




RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


# Temporarily down for maintenance!
#RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-FOR} !^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|swf|txt)$
#RewriteRule .* - [R=503,L]


# Reroute all requests on dev site to https
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev.mydomain.com$
#RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}



PassengerEnabled on
PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
RailsEnv development
RailsBaseURI /
PassengerAppRoot /home/account/rails_apps/dev.MyDomain


ErrorDocument 500 "<h2>Application error</h2>Rails application failed to start properly"
# Start CloudFlare:mydomain.com rewrite. Do not Edit 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L] 
# End CloudFlare rewrite.
```

Comment: Is this your complete htaccess code or you have more code?

Comment: Any thoughts on the matter?

Comment: Looks alright to me, can you try in a new browser to avoid 301 caching issues.

Comment: Yes, I tried in Firefox, Chrome and IE; all producing the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figures...I spend a couple of days searching out this problem and I arrive at a solution just seconds before getting into contact with tech support at Bluehost.

http://www.crsr.net/Notes/Apache-HTTPS-virtual-host.html

I needed to add a VirtualHost entry in httpd.conf for my Apache config. There was already one auto-generated by Bluehost when they installed the SSL cert, but not one for dev.mydomain.com

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443>
    ServerName dev.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.dev.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /home/account/public_html/subdomains/dev
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.com
    UseCanonicalName Off
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/dev.mydomain.com combined
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/dev.mydomain.com-bytes_log "%{%s}t %I .\n%{%s}t %O ."
    ## User account # Needed for Cpanel::ApacheConf
    UserDir enabled account
    <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_UserGroup account account
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_disable_suexec.c>
        <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
            SuexecUserGroup account account
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
        RUidGid account account
    </IfModule>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/account/public_html/subdomains/dev/cgi-bin/
    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile /var/cpanel/ssl/installed/certs/_wildcard__mydomain_com_[blah-blah-blah].crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/cpanel/ssl/installed/keys/[blah-blah-blah].key
    SSLCACertificateFile /var/cpanel/ssl/installed/cabundles/COMODO_CA_Limited_[blah-blah-blah].cabundle
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/dev.mydomain.com-ssl_log combined
    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
    <Directory "/home/account/public_html/subdomains/dev/cgi-bin">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    # To customize this VirtualHost use an include file at the following location
    # Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/ssl/2/account/mydomain.com/*.conf"

</VirtualHost>
```